# Erroring out on lodsb

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32

I am writing a fairly simple program to obtain user input integers as a string, validate them and add them to an array of integers. For some reason I keep getting an unhandled exception error when I hit the `lodsb` command.

Here is the relevant code bits. I have a feeling I am missing clearing or perserving something that `lodsb` uses, but I have not been able to put my finger on it. I have tried following other code bits doing similar things (not what is below) but they do not seem to work for me either. Any help in figuring out where I am going wrong would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    MAXSIZE = 10

getString   MACRO   varName
    push    ecx
    push    edx
    mov     edx, OFFSET varName
    mov     ecx, (SIZEOF varName) -1    ;; leave room for 0 byte
    call    ReadString
    pop     edx
    pop     ecx
ENDM

.data
newInt          BYTE    MAXSIZE DUP(0)  
.code
        NOTINT:
            getString       newInt
            mov     ecx, eax
        VALIDATE:
        VALLOOP:
            push    esi
            mov     eax, 0
            lodsb
            cmp         eax, 48         ; '0' is character 48
            displayString   notValid
            jb      NOTINT
            cmp         eax, 57         ; '9' is character 57
            displayString   notValid
            ja      NOTINT
            pop     esi
            loop    VALLOOP
```

Comment: `esi` is never even set, how do you expect `lodsb` to work? You are missing `mov esi, OFFSET varName` presumably. Read the instruction set reference and learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Thanks Jester. I was getting frustrated and more and more dumb by the minute. You just put me on the right path again.

Comment: FWIW, You put a call to `displayString` between the comparison and the branch. I would guess that `readString` is not trivial, so it very likely changes the flags, and the branch gets the wrong flags.

Comment: FWIW2, most assemblers will allow you to write `cmp eax,'0'` directly. And why not compare `AL` instead of `EAX`?

Answer (score 2):

I found several errors in your code.

- You never initialize the ESI register and so `lodsb` can not operate correctly.
- Even if you did setup ESI then the loop would be infinite because you `push` and `pop` ESI around the `lodsb` instruction and so it will always process the same byte.
- Are you sure the (macro)code in `displayString   notValid` preserves the state of the flags because the following `cmp` instruction depends on it?
- Both conditional jumps to *NOTINT* jump out of a block of code that has a value pushed on stack. This value will not get popped off and so the stack will get corrupted.

This could work:

```
.code
  NOTINT:
    getString newInt
    mov     ecx, eax
    mov     esi, offset newInt
    cld                  ;One too many of these won't harm!
  VALLOOP:
    lodsb
    cmp     al, '0'
    jb      NOTINT
    cmp     al, '9'
    ja      NOTINT
    loop    VALLOOP
```